# Kafka very high latency C#

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I am doing some performance tests on Apache Kafka to compare it with others like RabbitMQ and ActiveMQ. The idea is to use it on a messaging system for agents' communication.

I am testing multiple scenarios (one to one, broadcast and many to one) with different numbers of publishers and subscribers and so different loads. Even in the lowest load scenario of one to one with 10 pairs of agents sending 500 messages with 1ms delay between sends I am experiencing very high latencies (average of ~200ms). And if we go to 100 pairs the numbers rise to ~1500ms. The same thing happens on broadcast and many to one.

I am using Windows with Kafka 2.12-2.5.0 and zookeeper 3.6.1 with C# .Net client Confluent.Kafka 1.4.2. I have already tried some properties like LingerMs = 0 according to some posts I found. I have both Kafka and zookeeper with default settings.

I made a simple test code in which the problem happens:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Confluent.Kafka;

namespace KafkaSetupAgain
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int numberOfMessages = 500;
            int numberOfPublishers = 10;
            int numberOfSubscribers = 10;
            int timeOfRun = 30000;

            List<MCVESubscriber> Subscribers = new List<MCVESubscriber>();
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSubscribers; i++)
            {
                MCVESubscriber ZeroMqSubscriber = new MCVESubscriber();
                new Thread(() =>
                {
                    ZeroMqSubscriber.read(i.ToString());
                }).Start();
                Subscribers.Add(ZeroMqSubscriber);
            }


            Thread.Sleep(10000);//to make sure all subscribers started
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPublishers; i++)
            {
                MCVEPublisher ZeroMqPublisherBroadcast = new MCVEPublisher();
                new Thread(() =>
                {
                    ZeroMqPublisherBroadcast.publish(numberOfMessages, i.ToString());
                }).Start();
            }

            Thread.Sleep(timeOfRun);
            foreach (MCVESubscriber Subscriber in Subscribers)
            {
                Subscriber.PrintMessages("file.csv");
            }
        }

        public class MCVEPublisher
        {
            public void publish(int numberOfMessages, string topic)
            {
                var config = new ProducerConfig
                {
                    BootstrapServers = "localhost:9092",
                    LingerMs = 0,
                    Acks = 0,
                };
                var producer = new ProducerBuilder<Null, string>(config).Build();

                int success = 0;
                int failure = 0;
                Thread.Sleep(3500);
                for (int i = 0; i < numberOfMessages; i++)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(1);
                    long milliseconds = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.GetTimestamp() / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond;

                    var t = producer.ProduceAsync(topic, new Message<Null, string> { Value = milliseconds.ToString() });
                    t.ContinueWith(task => {
                        if (task.IsFaulted)
                        {
                            failure++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            success++;
                        }
                    });
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Success: " + success + " Failure:" + failure);

            }
        }

        public class MCVESubscriber
        {
            private List<string> prints = new List<string>();

            public void read(string topic)
            {
                var config = new ConsumerConfig()
                {
                    BootstrapServers = "localhost:9092",
                    EnableAutoCommit = false,
                    FetchErrorBackoffMs = 1,
                };

                var consumerConfig = new ConsumerConfig(config);
                consumerConfig.GroupId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                consumerConfig.AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Earliest;
                consumerConfig.EnableAutoCommit = false;

                using (var consumer = new ConsumerBuilder<Ignore, string>(config).Build())
                {
                    consumer.Subscribe(new[] { topic });

                    while (true)
                    {
                        var consumeResult = consumer.Consume();

                        long milliseconds = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.GetTimestamp() / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond;
                        prints.Add(consumeResult.Message.Value + ";" + milliseconds.ToString());
                    }

                    consumer.Close();
                }
            }

            public void PrintMessages(string path)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("printing " + prints.Count);
                File.AppendAllLines(path, prints);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Does someone what can be the problem? What configs can I change to 
improve latency?

Thanks,

Davide Costa

Answer (score 2):

Kafka is not really built for low latency message distribution, but for high availability.  It can be configured to have lower latency, but you start losing a lot of the advantages Kafka offers.

A few tips/comments below:

- On the `KafkaProducer` side, in general, you want to wait until there's enough messages to send, to as to batch messages more efficiently.  That's the `linger.ms` property you already mentioned.  Typically that is set to something like 50ms, so by setting it to zero, you're effectively telling the producer to send data as fast as it gets it.  This may make the producer more "chatty", but you have the assurance it will send the data to the cluster as soon as it gets it.
- However, once a message is "produced" into Kafka, it waits until it gets an ACK from the lower layer that the broker has received the message successfully.  There's multiple options here:

  - Consider a message as "received" once the message has been sent by the producer. That is, locally, once the network layer has finished sending it, the producer will consider it "sent and acknowledged"
  - Wait for an ACK from the leader broker which you're sending the message to, depending on which partition it gets assigned, so you at least know one broker has it.  *THIS IS THE DEFAULT.*
  - Wait for an ACK from the leader broker which you're sending the message to, PLUS an ACK from each of that partitions' replicas on the other brokers.  This means, if your cluster has a replication factor of 3, that the message is sent to broker 1 for example, it then replicates that to brokers 2 and 3, which have copies of the same partition, waits for those brokers to reply back saying they got the message, and only THEN reply back to the producer saying the message has been ACK'd.  This is typically used in environments where you never want the possibility of losing a single message, so you always guarantee that there will be three copies of your message before the producer moves on.

Official `acks` explanation from the Kafka docs:

https://kafka.apache.org/25/documentation.html#acks

There are other settings to consider like kafka producer compression and broker compression settings that might add more latency/overhead, but if you're using the defaults (no producer compression and `producer` option in the broker compression), there should be no additional latency in those steps.

Having said all that, I would suggest you try to set the `acks` option in the producer to 0, and see how your latency changes.  My guess is you will get much better latency, *BUT* also understand that there are no guarantees your messages are actually being received and stored correctly.  A flaky network, a network partition, etc, could cause you to lose data.  That might be ok for your use case, but just make sure you're aware of it.

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer. However, I have tried the use of acks = 0 in the producer and latencies remain around the same value (the best I can get with 10 pairs of agents exchanges messages is ~150ms). I have also checked the compression but is set as compression.type = none on producer.properties file and no reference on the server.properties. Can it be something else?

Comment: According to documentation Apache Kafka should be good for messaging and a good alternative to RabbitMQ and ActiveMQ (https://kafka.apache.org/uses). That's why I think I am doing something wrong

Comment: @DavideCosta At this point, I would try this to pinpoint where the delay is happening: Try to run your code on the same physical box as the kafka/zookeeper server, so there is zero network latency. Also, configure your kafka broker to only use one instance, and for zookeeper to also use only one instance.  Use IP addresses instead of hostnames to skip over DNS resolution.  Try to run it like that, and measure what your latency is, as well as keep an eye on how much CPU load there is per process.  If that latency number is acceptable, start adding back things to pinpoint what's causing the lag.

Comment: I did not mention that but I am running just one zookeeper instance and just one Kafka broker and all running at localhost. Regarding CPU usage, for the scenario with 10 pairs of agents, II only notice a spike of 50% on java virtual machine for about 2/3 seconds.

Comment: Another thing I noticed on the results is that in the 500 messages an agent sends to the respective pair, the first ~200/250 arrive all at the same timestamp even though they have been produced with almost ~500ms difference. The messages until that number (~250) are the cause of the big average latency. If I do the average from 250 to 500 I get a value of 8ms instead of the overall ~150ms

Comment: Did you find a solution yet?